# ArrayBuffer support in react-native c++

Tags: c++, reactjs, react-native

We are trying to use ArrayBuffer with react-native ( c++ ) and we get an "Unsupported" error. Checking the code we have seen something like this:

```
bool JSCRuntime::isArrayBuffer(const jsi::Object& /*obj*/) const {
  // TODO: T23270523 - This would fail on builds that use our custom JSC
  // auto typedArrayType = JSValueGetTypedArrayType(ctx_, objectRef(obj),
  // nullptr);  return typedArrayType == kJSTypedArrayTypeArrayBuffer;
  throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported");
}
```

In file https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactCommon/jsi/JSCRuntime.cpp#L894
What does it mean?

Are there some plan to support ArrayBuffer in react-native?

Comment: Please include the relevant code from your file in the question, rather than as a link. Links go stale and the code at the end of the link may change.

Comment: This question seems more fitted for the projects github page.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts the link brings to the code we have post here.
We post here this question because we have follow these steps on the official github page. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/new/choose
If there's another place to post this I'm here to listen your advices. Thank you very much. Regards

Comment: Stackoverflow is not Github.As I said, your link will go stale and invalidate your question.